# One-sided truncated normal distribution in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

In scipy, is there any way to sample from a normal distribution that has only been truncated on one side?

Say I have a standard normal distribution, with the domain `(-inf, 0]`.

The `scipy.stats.truncnorm` class provides utilities for distributions with a specific lower and upper bound, but is there a good way to do this if you only have one or the other, short of `scipy.stats.truncnorm(a=-9999999, b=0, loc=0, scale=1)`?

Comment: You can use `a=-numpy.inf`.

Comment: oh! awesome. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `np.inf` (or `-np.inf`) to set the bounds results in the distribution being unbounded on that side:

```py
scipy.stats.truncnorm(a=-np.inf, b=0, loc=0, scale=1)
```

H/t to @warren-weckesser for the answer in comments.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is the [Half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) (its mirror to the y-axis to be precise), a special case where the [Folded Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) and the Truncated Normal Distribution are equivalent. scipy also provides that distribution: [scipy.stats.foldnorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.foldnorm.html). The only reason I'm mentioning this is (not to be pedantic) because it is quite convoluted how scipy and numpy define these distributions (see below: `mu` & `sigma` vs. `beta`, `scale`, `loc`, `a` & `b`)

Run this in a notebook and the differences become apparent:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

resolution=10000

mu, sigma = 0.0, 0.2
normdist = lambda x: 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) )
f = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, resolution)

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(f, 'auto', density=True)
plt.plot(bins, [normdist(x) for x in bins], 'r--', linewidth=2, label='(np)norm.dist')


beta=2.0
scale=1/np.sqrt(2)*(2*sigma)
nd = st.gennorm(beta, loc=mu, scale=scale)
x = np.linspace(nd.ppf(0.01), nd.ppf(0.99), resolution)
plt.plot(x, nd.pdf(x),'g-', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='(sc)gennorm pdf')
print(f'mean: {nd.mean()}, std: {nd.std()}')

c=0.0
fnd = st.foldnorm(c, loc=0.0, scale=scale)

x = np.arange(-1.0, 5.0, 1/resolution)
plt.plot(x, fnd.pdf(x),'k-', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='(sc)foldnorm pdf')
# count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(fnd.rvs(size=resolution), 'auto', density=True)

print(f'mean: {fnd.mean()}, std: {fnd.std()}')

a=0
b=np.inf
tnd = st.truncnorm(a=a, b=b, loc=0, scale=scale)
plt.plot(x, tnd.pdf(x),'b-', lw=1, alpha=0.6, label='(sc)truncnorm pdf')
# count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(tnd.rvs(size=resolution), 'auto', density=True)

plt.plot(x, [normdist(x) for x in x], 'r--', lw=1, label='(np)norm.dist')

print(f'mean: {fnd.mean()}, std: {fnd.std()}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```